# Blade IF ELSE and Extends

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I want do check simple condition and then decide what template should I extend. I want to do something like this:

```
@if(Auth::check())
   @extends("template/index")
@else
    @extends("template/login")
@endif
```

But when I do, I get both templates extended ....

Answer (score 1):

You should create a new variable based on a condition using the `@php` blade directive:

```
@php
    $template = Auth::check() ? 'index' : 'login';
@endphp

@extends('template/' . $template)
```

Comment: doesn´t work that way, idk if i´m doing something wrong.

Comment: @A.Rodrigues Please see update. I think Laravel changed the directive syntax

Comment: @a-rodrigues have you had a chance to check?

Comment: I try to check, but don´t find nthing usefull